# How to get to a specify Cell from a different CollectionView with same CellIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Well I am new in swift and I am trying to do the next:

I have 2 CollectionViews with same CollectionViewCell, first one (mainCollectionView) is almost on all screen with paging (1 cell on screen), the second one (smallCollectionView) is something like a preview on the bottom (with all the cells shown). I need to make that mainCollectionView will scroll at the cell that was selected on the smallCollectionView, I tried to do like this:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return templatesArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let universallCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "universallCellIdent", for: indexPath) as! UniversalCollectionViewCell
    universallCell.imageOutlet.image = templatesArray[indexPath.row]

    return universallCell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView == smallCollectionView
    {
        let selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(index: indexPath.row)
        mainCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: selectedIndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    }
}
```

but when I do this function:

```
mainCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: selectedIndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
```

it crashes because: reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path:  {length = 1, path = 1}'

I don't know why, and how that should be managed, here is a pic of Interface builder, maybe that will help in understanding of what I want to do:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Working perfectly now, the thing was that I am using Horizontal paging so I need other position than .top

```
mainCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
mainCollectionView.reloadData()
```

So it worked like a charm!

Comment: Make sure both of your collection view are populated with same data as the error which you are getting is mentioning that the index on which you are scrolling doesn't exist for that collection view

Comment: You aren't initialize correctly selectedIndexPath for collectionView and why you're creating new IndexPath instance if you receive one by indexPath parameter? use it directly. I mean: mainCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)

Comment: yeah I figured out that 2 minutes ago that there is no need for new IndexPath, my mistke